# How can you export a list of "Sent Items" in Outlook in a specific format?

Tags: vba, outlook, reporting

I need to generate a list of Sent Items in the following format.

```
<sent to:> <Subject> <Date>
```

Example:

```
a@a.com "First Letter" 1/1/2011

b@b.com "Check out this second letter" 1/2/2011
```

Any help is appreciated. Looks like this guy can do it via VBA here - http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/Office_Productivity/Groupware/Outlook/Q_24483105.html

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

I cannot test at the moment, but this should get you started:

```
Dim oApp As Outlook.Application
Dim oNS As NameSpace
Dim oSent As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim strMessage As String
Dim strAddresses As String
Dim i, j

Set oApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set oNS = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set oSent = oNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail)

For i = 1 To oSent.Count
    For j = 1 To oSent(i).Recipients.Count
    ''http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb176763(v=office.12).aspx
        strAddresses = strAddresses & ";" _
        & oSent(i).Recipients(j).Address
    Next
    strMessage = strMessage _
    & Mid(strAddresses, 2) _
    & oSent(i).Subject _
    & oSent(i).SentOn & vbCrLf
Next
```